# Using a regular expression to find all noun phrases in a paragraph following the occurrence of a specific phrase

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, findall

I have a data frame of paragraphs, which I have (*can) split into word tokens and sentence tokens and am looking to find all the noun phrases following any instance where the phrase: "contribute to" or "donate to" occurs.

Or really some form of that, so:

```
"Contributions are welcome to be made to the charity of your choice." 

---> would return: "the charity of your choice"
```

and

```
"blah blah blah donations, in honor of Firstname Lastname, can be made to ABC Foundation"

---> would return: "ABC Foundation"
```

I've created a regular expression work-around that captures the correct phrase about 90% of the time... see below:

```
text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
donation = TokenSearcher(text).findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")
donation = [' '.join(tokens) for tokens in donation]
return donation
```

I'd like to clean up that regular expression to get rid of the "{,15}" requirements because it's missing some of the values that I need. However, I'm not too polished with the "greedy" expressions and can't get it to work correctly.

so this phrase:

```
While she lived a full life , had many achievements and made many 
**contributions** , FirstName is remembered by most for her cheerful smile ,
colorful track suits , and beautiful necklaces hand made by daughter FirstName .
FirstName always cherished her annual visit home for Thanksgiving to visit
brother FirstName LastName
```

is returning: "visit brother FirstName Lastname" due to the previous mentioning of contributions even though the word "to" comes well after 15 words later.

Comment: "even though the word 'to' comes well after 15 words later."  Well.  That's what `.*` *does*.  It explicitly matches *any number of characters.*

Comment: I thought the "{,15}" that follows it caps it at a maximum of 15 words though.

Comment: That happens before the "contrib.*" match.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad because there is no single answer to this not-a-single-question.

Comment: I was under the impression that <\.> would be checking for a period then the <.*>{,15} checks for any number of words up to fifteen followed by the word "contrib... " or "donat..." . Its sounds like I'm wrong about that but don't really understand why.

Comment: If I understand well if you find any of the 3 words: 
donat
contrib
gifts
in that case if you see a "to" later on, then you need the rest of the sentence after the to. Is it possible that there will be a "to" after these words in the same sentence which won't belong to the above words? If yes, then I believe it would be hard to give a rule..

Comment: In every instance that I've seen (quite a few) the word "donat | contrib | gifts" is always followed by the word to... either directly after, or after a few words in between. In all those cases the name of an organization or entity to be donated to always directly follows the "to". Is that what you were asking? You seem to have my issue understood, I'm just a little thrown off by what you're trying to clarify.

Comment: Ive made a regexp, will post it now. If I need to correct it, please help me with few example sentences and desired outputs.

Comment: Most you only use Regex? Won't state-of-art parser, chunk, postagger help you better?

Comment: @BenPrice this is why your "0-15 words" quantifier isn't working the way you expect. http://s24.postimg.org/kbgu86crp/words.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're struggling with how to restrict your search criteria to a single sentence. So just use the NLTK to break your text into sentences (which it can do far better than just looking at periods), and your problem disappears.

```
sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(x)  # `x` is a single string, as in your example
recipients = []
for sent in sents:
    m = re.search(r"\b(contrib|donat).*?\bto\b([^.,;]*)", sent)
    if m:
        recipients.append(m.group(2).strip())
```

For further work, I also recommend that you use a better tool than `Text`, which is intended for simple interactive explorations. If you do want to do more with your texts, the nltk's `PlaintextCorpusReader` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, that part is essential (and standard; somehow I dropped it when typing this answer.)

Comment: so this works great, but when I do the sent_tokenize, its ending sentences after words like "Dr." and "St." and "Mt." so a phrase like "In lieu of flowers , memorial donations may be made to the research of Dr. Giuseppe Giaccone at Georgetown University" returns only "the research of Dr". Do you know if there is any type of work around for the abbreviation issue or a different way to tokenize the sentences that would capture those as one total token?

Comment: Does it now? I tried this exact sentence, and the sentence tokenizer handled "Dr." correctly as not ending a sentence. Abbreviations are exactly the kind of thing a sentence tokenizer is designed to handle. Of course *your* regexp-based NP extraction stops at the next period (it extracts `[^.,;]*`), so although the sentence is complete, you only extract the "noun phrase" until the next punctuation. For better performance, replace your regexp approach with POS-tagging and/or an NP chunker (see [chapter 7](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) of the nltk book).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that is certainly the next step. Do you know if there's a way to tweak the regex so that it just captures everything till the end of the sentence? Also, you're right about the sent_tokenizer working on Dr. and St. , I think it just messes up with Mt.

Comment: Okay well I just removed the period from the last character bracket... that seemed to work, so now it just checks for commas or semicolons or just captures the rest of the sentence.    re.search(r"\b(contrib|donat).*?\bto\b([^,;]*)", sent). Thanks for all the help ya'll

Comment: Good thinking... you don't need to stop at the end of the sentence anymore. It must still capture too much on occasion (or even too little: some names and titles do contain commas), but if you're satisfied with its performance there's no need to bother with real NLP...

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:contrib|donat|gifts)(?=[^\.]+\bto\b[^\.]+).*to\s([^\.]+)
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/wW5qP6/1) 
If works and does what you need then let me know and I will explain my regexp.

Comment: Sorry I won't able to answer how to apply it in your program code and tell if the function you are trying to use supports all the used expressions or not.

Comment: so I got this implemented but am getting a "error: nothing to repeat", which I googled and looks like its a bug in the python regex implementation but I'm not sure exactly whats causing it.

Comment: Backslashes don't work as escapes (and aren't needed) inside character ranges. `[^\.]` matches everything except a period _or a backslash._